# Yii displaying array of options with labels in dropDownList

Tags: php, forms, yii2

Is there any way to display array with labels as a dropDownList options?
This is what i have on mind:

```
$form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList([
$list_options => $list_labels,
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert these two arrays into one, where options are keys and labels are values of array. You may use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) for this:

```
$form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList(array_combine($list_options, $list_labels));
```

See also [`dropDownList()` documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#dropDownList()-detail).

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need. One more thing. Index 0 is visible at the top of my dropDownList. Is there any chance i can get rid of it?

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
$form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList([
 'value1' => 'label1', 
 'value2' => 'label2', 
 'value3' => 'label3', 
]);
```